# How to close/destroy a Firebase reference in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the scenario -:

A firebase reference is created

```
Firebase myRef = new Firebase(url)  // In Main Activity
```

User Clicks a button navigates to other activity .

onPause() for Main activity is called.Is there a way to destroy this constructor ?

This reference is creating some unexpected behavior.
Simply calling finish() for Main activity will destroy it or not?

Comment: GC take care of all this in JAVA why are you taking worries ?

Comment: where exactly do you create the ref and what do you do with it before onPause happens? what is the 'unexpected behaviour'?

Comment: @muratgu I wanted to stop calling the method onDataChange() .I was thinking about destroying the constructor but as Frank has mentioned Removing the Listener will do the trick. dex Yes memory is not a problem here at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Firebase` objects are lightweight references to locations in your Firebase Database. There is no need (nor ability) to manage their life-cycle. So as @dex commented, you can just let the Java garbage collector take care of them.

On the other hand, once you start attaching listeners (e.g. `addValueEventListener()`) you should detach them in the corresponding life-cycle event with `removeEventListener()`. Also see [Firebase adding listeners in adapters in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526780/firebase-adding-listeners-in-adapters-android) and [How stop Listening to firebase location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378446/how-stop-listening-to-firebase-location-in-android)

Comment: Yes Frank that is exactly what i was trying to achieve 2nd link was helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify for any reading this for code reference in the future.In the 2nd link you have mentioned var listener = ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { // implementation of the onDataChange and onCanceled }); The Data type should be ValueEventListener instead of var.

Comment: @Frank I am adding user in firebase database by setValue method and on addOnSuccessListener i finish the activity but it skip some keys value mean it did not add complete json data when i comment the finish activity it work properly how to solve that issue