# Firebase Base listener behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Will the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` be fired even after the parent `activity` that hosts the `listRef` has been destroyed?

```
 DatabaseReference listRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.Client + "/"+Constants.branch);
            listRef.keepSynced(true);
            listRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Database listeners are not associated with an activity or other context. If you don't want them to fire after the activity has been destroyed, you should remove the listener in the correct lifecycle method of your activity.

Also see:

- [How to close/destroy a Firebase reference in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521256/how-to-close-destroy-a-firebase-reference-in-android)

Comment: Why is it not associated with the context?
doc says that keepSynced true loads into the RAM, so how long will the instance persist in RAM?

Comment: Calling `ref.keepSynced(true)` essentially means that Firebase adds an empty listener to the location, so that the data is kept up to date in memory while the app is active. The data will be removed once the app exits, or when you call `ref.keepSynced(false)` *and* all other references to that same location have been removed.