# No event listener removal for Firebase DatabaseReference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

Hey do I need to remove this listener at some point, or does it get removed on its own? I have this called in a fragment within my activity, and users can go to another view without this one being destroyed. Therefore not sure if I am somehow suppose to remove this in an `onDestroy`, `onPause` call? I do not see a way to remove it since it is a `DatabaseReference`

Here is the code:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
  mDatabase.child("projects").orderByChild("viewCount").limitToLast(15).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
```

Answer (score 8):

As the answer superman links to show: you indeed will need to remove the listener in the opposite lifecycle event.

To remove a listener, you need to keep the [handle that is returned when you call `addChildListener()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)):

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("projects").orderByChild("viewCount").limitToLast(15);
ChildEventListener listener = query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { ...
```

And then [pass it to `removeEventListener()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)):

```
query.removeChildEventListener(listener);
```

You can see that I explicitly use a `Query` here, since that is what you actually attach your listener to. But if you have a plain `DatabaseReference` the same methods are available, since `DatabaseReference` inherits from `Query`.

Comment: you may like to reattach the listener like query.addChildEventListener(listener) on your on onResume, onRestart or onStart depending on requirement.... because if you remove the listeners and minimize the app and bring it up again it will have stopped listening

Answer (score 4):

**Firebase** objects are lightweight references to locations in your Firebase Database. There is **no need (nor ability)** to manage their life-cycle. So, you can just let the Java garbage collector take care of them.

**However,** once you start attaching listeners (e.g. `addValueEventListener()`) you should detach them in the corresponding life-cycle event with `removeEventListener()`. Also see [Firebase adding listeners in adapters in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526780/firebase-adding-listeners-in-adapters-in-android) and [How stop Listening to firebase location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378446/how-stop-listening-to-firebase-location-in-android).

Comment: so adding a ChildEventListener ... does that require then for the listener to be removed if so how do I call it because there is no method like that on the DatabaseReference?

Answer (score 2):

As Frank says, you need to remove the listener from the **exact** DatabaseReference, not just the root DatabaseReference as I was doing.

To simplify this, I created a small class below:

```
public class FirebaseListenerRef {

    private ValueEventListener listener;
    private DatabaseReference ref;

    public FirebaseListenerRef(DatabaseReference ref, ValueEventListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.ref = ref;

        // Start listening on this ref.
        ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
    }

    public void detach() {
        ref.removeEventListener(listener);
    }
}
```

To use this, just create and detach it in paired lifecycle events, e.g.

```
private FirebaseListenerRef myFirebaseListenerRef;

public void onAttach(Content context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    myFirebaseListenerRef = new FirebaseListenerRef(
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path-to-listen-on", 
        new ValueEventListener() { 
            ... implement the listener logic
         }
      );
}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if ( myFirebaseListenerRef != null ) {
    // Detach our listener from its reference
        myFirebaseListenerRef.detach();
        myFirebaseListenerRef == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is about time for android to think about a class of variables and methods which are not null by birth (so they could be declared as private nonNull -> and so on) if they have not got them already.. the null pointer reference is mostly a nuisance in my experience...

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Query` to add `addValueEventListener`. Then you should remove the listener using `Query` instance not `DatabaseReference` instance.

In question with `DatabaseReference` the developer was using `orderByChild` which is of type `Query` So to remove the listener we need to get reference to Query instance and then use `removeEventListener`.

Here is my example of removing the listener:

```
ValueEventListener carChangesListener;
Query ownerId_Query;
```

Then

```
DatabaseReference bikeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cars");
        ownerId_Query = bikeRef.orderByChild("ownerId").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        carChangesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    /*NOTE: handle cars response here*/
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No car found for this user.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(HOME_TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error!" + databaseError.toException().getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        ownerId_Query.addValueEventListener(bikeChangesListener);
```

Now to remove the `carChangesListener` I will do following:

```
ownerId_Query.removeEventListener(carChangesListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same problem. Removing the listener from DatabaseReference does nothing. This mistake doesn't event show up in the logs, and most tutorials fail to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DatabaseReference dbRef;
ValueEventListener mSendEventListner;

dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(phone);

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {              
                   //
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //
            }
};
dbRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
mSendEventListner = valueEventListener;


//REMOVE VALUE EVENTLISTNER...
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mSendEventListner != null) {
        dbRef.removeEventListener(mSendEventListner);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used a ValueEventListener with a child, you must:

```
ValueEventListener listener;
onCreate(....){
    listener = mDatabase.child("projects").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { ...... }
}
```

And remove listener:

```
mDatabase.child("projects").removeEventListener(listener);
```

The most important thing in this RemoveEventListener is the child () function.